# URI parsing errors

Tags: java, android, uri

I am getting follow error when sending the data as json to the application server from Android mobile.But the application works without any issue if we send data from pc- browsers. Is it something we have to do when sending data from android browser?

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 271: http://oracleapps.veeralab.com:8080/emyed-whiteboard/pubsub/27c95d04-9783-447b-b333-bcc7b3bbb6b7/01815406-7699-4c2c-ae4b-4eefdbbcbdf0.topic?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=1.0&X-Atmosphere-Transport=polling&X-Cache-Date=0&X-Atmosphere-Post-Body=message={%22action%22:%22joinName%22,%22parameters%22:%22usersName%22:%22veera,%20job,%20ram%22,%22timestamp%22:1349724088883,%22user%22:%22job%22,%22whiteboardId%22:%2227c95d04-9783-447b-b333-bcc7b3bbb6b7%22}&jsonpTransport=jQuery180031574026358131124_1349709680844
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3002) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3092) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3034) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:595) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:857) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
```

Comment: encode your URI, get rid of the braces

Comment: @16dots But i dont understand why it is working in the computer browser, it should fail there too

Comment: Because your browser automatically encodes everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

To remove invalid characters, either use the URLEncoder or Uri Parsing as follows.

**Starting with the following information**

```
String BASE_URL = "http://oracleapps.veeralab.com:8080/emyed-whiteboard/pubsub/27c95d04-9783-447b-b333-bcc7b3bbb6b7/01815406-7699-4c2c-ae4b-4eefdbbcbdf0.topic"
String QUERY = "X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=1.0&X-Atmosphere-Transport=polling&X-Cache-Date=0&X-Atmosphere-Post-Body=message={%22action%22:%22joinName%22,%22parameters%22:%22usersName%22:%22veera,%20job,%20ram%22,%22timestamp%22:1349724088883,%22user%22:%22job%22,%22whiteboardId%22:%2227c95d04-9783-447b-b333-bcc7b3bbb6b7%22}&jsonpTransport=jQuery180031574026358131124_1349709680844"
```

**You can use the URLEncoder**

```
String url = BASE_URL + "?" + URLEncoder.encode(QUERY, "utf-8");
```

**OR You can use Uri Parsing**

```
String uri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL)
            .buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter("X-Atmosphere-tracking-id", "0")
            .appendQueryParameter("X-Atmosphere-Framework", "1")
            .appendQueryParameter("X-Atmosphere-Post-Body", "message={%22action%22:%22joinName%22,%22parameters%22:%22usersName%22:%22veera,%20job,%20ram%22,%22timestamp%22:1349724088883,%22user%22:%22job%22,%22whiteboardId%22:%2227c95d04-9783-447b-b333-bcc7b3bbb6b7%22}")
            ... //your other params
            .build().toString();
```

My recommendation would be to use the Uri Parsing method to ensure nothing is encoded which shouldn't be, but that you still end with a valid uri.